# TypeScript - duplicate identifier

Tags: typescript

In my TypeScript 2.0 code (in Visual Studio 2015), I have:

```
var lang = navigator.language 
         ? navigator.language 
         : navigator.systemLanguage;
```

With that, I get this error:

```
Build:Property 'systemLanguage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

However, if I add this to one of my d.ts files:

```
interface Navigator {
  systemLanguage: string;
}
```

Then I get:

```
TS2300  Duplicate identifier 'systemLanguage'.
```

How do I break this TypeScript deadlock?

Comment: strange: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Navigator%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20systemLanguage%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20lang%20%3D%20navigator.language%20%7C%7C%20navigator.systemLanguage%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(lang)%3B

Comment: @Inferon, what is "strange" about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I am deducing that `navigator` is a variable of type `Navigator`. From the first error you posted, I would have guessed that the issue is that either (1) that `Navigator` interface does not have a property called `systemLanguage` or (2) that you are not specifying that `navigator` is of type `Navigator` in your code file. From the second error you posted, I am fairly certain that your problem is due to issue (2).

Since Typescript compiles all .ts files, when you add the `Navigator` interface with the `systemLanguage` property, it's finding that there is already another interface with the same name and same property, thus the second error.

I think what you need to do is (1) find where `Navigation` is defined, (2) import that definition into the file that contains the code that you reference first and (3) type `navigator` as being of type `Navigator`.

EDIT: Here is an example:

```
// your-code-file.ts
import Navigator from './path-to-code-file-with-navigator/navigator.ts'

...

let navigator:Navigator = ...;

...

var lang = navigator.language 
         ? navigator.language 
         : navigator.systemLanguage;


// navigator.ts
interface Navigator {
    language: string;
    systemLanguage: string;
}
```

Comment: `navigator` is actually `windows.navigator` in all browsers.

Comment: This code deals with current browsers and Internet Explorer. IE has `systemLanguage` and not `language`.

Comment: `Navigator` is defined in `lib.d.ts`, so I shouldn't touch it there.

Comment: ok, the problem was that I thought that you were defining navigator as a variable. If it's a windows's property, try replacing your `navigator` references with `(<any>window).navigator`

Comment: Guess that will have to do. Using `(<any>navigator).systemLanguage` worked okay, so I removed my interface definition and the compiler is happy.

Answer (score 1):

Navigator is defined in lib.d.ts. systemLanguage is no longer a property of Navigator interface. Check here 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts

Looks like commit made on Apr 11, 2016 removes the systemLanguage.

Comment: It is still a part of all Internet Explorer browsers, so my code has to use it. I agree that it is no longer a part of the standard!